# Does rounding away commas increase performance?

Tags: javascript, performance

I have a simple game loop that looks like this:

```
let dt = 0
let last = 0

const gameLoop = ms => {
  const t = ms / 1000

  dt = t - last
  last = t

  console.log(dt)

  requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop)
}

requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop)
```

Right now I'm stuying a way where I'm able to make movement and Animation consistent between different framerates. To accomplish that I have to multiply the delta time  `dt` with objects in my game.

Right now when I log `dt` to the console, I get a rather long number: `0.0166700000285`

Though I don't need such a accurate number to multiply my objects speed. So my question is if it would increase performance if I would fix the amount of decimals. For example `0.01667`

If yes, by how much?

Thanks :)

Comment: In JavaScript, numbers are all represented the same way.

Comment: Both are floats so there is no impact to performance

Comment: The biggest performance impact you have there is the `console.log`, as far as I can tell. To answer your question: no, both are numbers (in this case floats) so there should be no relevant impact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, rounding the floating point numbers will decrease the performance since it is an additional operation.

Decimal representation is just for us humans. The javascript runtime and the floating point unit  operate on floating point numbers and don't care how many decimals there are on the decimal representation of the floating point numbers.

Comment: What about using the rounded number to do multiplaying operations. Aren't they faster to compute since there are less numbers to chew?

Comment: @ImStifler - Internally, all numbers in JavaScript are 64-bit floating point values (using [IEEE 754 representation](http://steve.hollasch.net/cgindex/coding/ieeefloat.html)). It doesn't matter how many decimal positions it takes to represent one of those values, all arithmetic operations use all 64 bits. There's absolutely nothing gained by truncating the value after, say, five decimal points.

Answer (score -1):

Im just typing whats inside my head:
First we need to understand how computer works. Little bit to the basic, inside you ram all you see from a data occupies certain bit of space. We can guess more chars represent more bits required to store and process them.
Even more if we go to multiplication, just like our brain we need to see the entire number, store it in our head and do it. More challenging for more numbers there are in the decimal.

Its so low-level its kinda difficult to see with naked eyes.

Maybe relevant:
I play a game a lot. All games have limit to max number they can calculate, not because my system cant handle that. But because efficiency. And something to do with the architecture of os running it (32/64bit thing)
So if you are doing as efficient you can do, you will have time to round it and maybe limit the decimals. 
But if you're dealing with less than 10 numbers decimal, i'd say not so important.
But yes it has perf gain to have less numbers of decimals

How much perf gain:
I'd say not much if you run this process less than 
few thousand/sec. (Source: personal opinion)
And that is if you actually have to run it that many times per sec.
I see stuff goin on in the servers and this doesnt seem to be very less impactful than other optimizations we can do.

Hope it helps